# Rails 3 - Simplemodal pop up with forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simplemodal

I am trying to use [Simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) as a pop up box on an index page and put a form to add a new user inside it. It's not working, says there is an undefined method. How do I make this work? Does it have to do with :remote?

EDIT - Here's some code to hopefully explain a little better - from index.html.erb

```
<div id='basic-modal'>
   <input type='button' name='basic' value='Demo' class='basic'/>
</div>
   <!-- modal content -->
<div id="basic-modal-content">
      <%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

My form is the standard scaffold form, my Client model has a place to add some basic information about a client. My controller is the standard controller that is generated with scaffold, and my application.html.erb adds the required .js files. When I take the

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

out and put in just plain text, it works just fine. Does that help?

Comment: This wouldn't have anything to do with :remote since it appears that you aren't doing anything with asynchronous requests.  You should post the exact error message you are getting and your Javascript code before anyone can take a stab at helping you.

Comment: Does this help?  undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @user.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't found the answer to using simplemodal for a modal box, I found this tutorial at Nettus which uses modalbox and facebox:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-build-an-unobtrusive-login-system-in-rails/

With a few changes for rails 3, this helped me put a form inside a modal box with no problems.